# Can't seem to download or uninstall HomeBrew

Tags: terminal, homebrew

[Error when installing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFrFQ.jpg)
[Error when uninstalling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAYkp.jpg)

Currently trying to help a fellow student install HomeBrew but getting this error every time we are trying to download HomeBrew. Tried various scripts for uninstalling as well but also getting errors.

Any solutions?

Comment: Looks like failed to create `/usr/local/bin` directory, also you dont need to use `sudo` permission to create such directory.

Answer (score 0):

This is my `/usr/local/bin` directory (you don't need `sudo` permission for it):

```
$ ls -al /usr/local/bin | less
drwxr-xr-x  2466 ruichen  admin      78912 Oct 22 00:46 .
drwxr-xr-x    21 root     wheel        672 Aug 22 18:21 ..
-rw-r--r--     1 ruichen  admin          0 Oct 23  2019 .keepme
lrwxr-xr-x     1 ruichen  admin         37 Oct 16 13:56 2to3 -> ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1/bin/2to3
lrwxr-xr-x     1 ruichen  admin         41 Oct 16 13:56 2to3-3.9 -> ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1/bin/2to3-3.9
lrwxr-xr-x     1 ruichen  admin         38 Sep  8 00:51 411toppm -> ../Cellar/netpbm/10.86.24/bin/411toppm
lrwxr-xr-x     1 ruichen  admin         37 Nov  1  2020 4channels -> ../Cellar/libraw/0.20.2/bin/4channels
...
```